# Direct Connect RDS Latency Expectations

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, aws-direct-connect

Recently we have moved our databases to `AWS RDS` with applications OnPrem, Obviously, latency was huge so we provisioned direct connect with Megaport between `AWS Oregon region(RDS)` and our data centers(applications) in San Francisco.

But surprisingly we did not see any major difference for latency(please find attached results and below data), It's almost similar to the connection over the internet.

```
OnPrem App - OnPrem DB (Seconds) Insert: 0.112
OnPrem App - AWS DB Over Direct Connect(Seconds)  Insert: 1.332
OnPrem App - AWS DB Over Internet (Seconds) Insert: 1.50
```

Is this expected?
Do we have any options to improve latency?
Please provide any checkpoints for improvements.

Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

Latency on uncongested routes is largely a factor of distance along with the number of hops in the link.

Assuming, your DC has uncongested connections to the Internet and AWS sure does. For small requests congestion is not going to be an issue and latency will be relatively low.

However that's not guaranteed and could vary from reasonable to terrible at any time. The Internet tends to suffer a degree of packet loss causing re-transmission which increases latency. These effects would be more noticable with a larger traffic volume.

What Direct Connect gets you along with security improvements is a guaranteed latency and bandwidth. Not only is your request marginally quicker, you can ramp up the volume and be sure that the performance won't get any worse.

Megaport publishes [latency figures](https://www.megaport.com/network-latency/) for their part of the network.

Unfortunately there are not any RDS options that would reduce the latency further. Other strategies such as local read-replicas or local caching may be suitable for your application.

Disclaimer: I work for Megaport